JIRA Structure Plugin: How to avoid closedSprint() groups
On Jira Structure plugin, I was trying to include only active and future sprints for every team in the program.
Here's how i did:

I filtered issues by project and "sprint in (opensprint(), futureSprint()),
I grouped by sprint,
I inserted issues from the board

it returns me the active sprint, the future sprints, and also all past closed sprints where current sprint's issues where planned and not finished.
I'd like to find a way to avoid displaying the closed Sprints.
If i filter "sprint not in closedSprint()", the issues planned in the past closed sprint and present in the current active sprint disappear.
